# Uncaught ReferenceError: imgError is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onerror

Tags: javascript, html

En el siguiente código llamo mi imagen, donde `$datos` me trae una url almacenada en mi base de datos (hasta ahí funciona correctamente), y con la función declarada en `onerror` intento reemplazar por una imagen en caso de que no sea una imágen válida

**HTML**

```
<img src="<?php echo $datos['url_img'];?>" alt="Imágen del curso" class="img_curso_info" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

**JS**

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "../img/fondo.jpg";
    return true;
}
```

Pero en `console` del navegador me imprime el error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: imgError is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código funciona perfectamente, como se puede comprobar aquí:

```js
function imgError(image) {
    image.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
}
```

```html
<img src="<?php echo $datos['url_img'];?>" alt="Imágen del curso" class="img_curso_info" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

En el ejemplo he dejado tal cual el `src` de tu código, que aquí no encontrará porque no se tiene acceso a `$datos['url_img']`, y el `onerror` asigna entonces esta imagen: `https://via.placeholder.com/150`.

El error en tu contexto puede deberse a que la función `imgError()` [no esté incluida en tu contexto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined) (por ejemplo si está en un archivo aparte que no has incluido). O que no esté cargada todavía cuando ocurre el `onerror`, eso podría ocurrir en una página que se recarga con lentitud por ejemplo.

Ese es uno de los motivos por los que nunca es aconsejable usar funciones *in line*. Aquí, por el motivo que sea, en el momento en que ocurre la llamada de tu función *in line*, dicha función no está disponible, y se produce el error.

### Una solución mejor

Esto se puede resolver, para el caso concreto de las imágenes, asignando un *listener* a nivel de Javascript. Aquí, para alcanzar el elemento ìmg`le he dado un`id` (que deber ser único)  y luego le he asignado un listener para los errores (puse uno para la carga también por si te interesa).

La ventaja de esto no es que sólo te funcionará porque hasta que el elemento no se cargue no será lanzado el control de errores, sino que además tu HTML queda totalmente independiente de tu código Javascript (si observas el `onerror` desaparece en el HTML, porque el elemento es escuchado en Javascript por su id), haciendo el código más fácil de mantener.

```js
let img=document.getElementById("mImage");

img.onload = function() {
  console.log(`Imagen cargada, tamaño: ${img.width}x${img.height}`);
};

img.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log('Control de errores ocurriendo');
  e.target.src='https://via.placeholder.com/150';
};
```

```html
<img id="mImage" src="src erróneo a propósito" alt="Imágen del curso" class="img_curso_info" />
```